# How can I pass data to a segue when the destination controller is embedded in a navigation controller

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I need to segue to destination view controller (which is a tableview controller) to which I need to pass some data. I also need to have a navbar in the destination view controller. So I embedded the destination view controller in a navigation controller. segue.destination now points to the embedded navigation controller. It does not help to access the destination controller directly since it probably creates another instance. How can I either (1) create a navigation bar directly in the destination view controller (which is a tableview controller) or (2) send the data to the destination controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the `segue.destination` to a `UINavigationController` and then the the navigation controller's root view controller to a view controller class of your choice.

```
switch segue.destination {
case let navigationController as UINavigationController:
    if let controller = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? UIViewController {
        // controller.property = value
    }
}
```